# How to invoke private method in enum type with mockito

Tags: junit, enums, mockito

```
public enum SPHttpClient {
    ;

private static fun(clientInstance) {
    HttpPost postRequest;
    /* some processing*/
    clientInstance.execute(postRequest);
    // I need to mock this execute statement
 }

}
```

Writing Junit test on private method fun,

**How to invoke private method which is in ENUM type  and also I need to mock clientInstance which is passed through argument of private method??**

```
SPHttpClient spHttpClient;
final Method method = spHttpClient.getClass().getDeclaredMethod("fun", HttpClient.class);
        method.setAccessible(true);
        Object actual = method.invoke(spHttpClient, mockHttpClient);
```

I think  `getclass` wont work for enums ??

Comment: Where does the `clientInstance` come from?

Comment: `clientInstance` is type of `HttpClient` object, which was passed as an argument to `fun` function

Answer (score 0):

The signature of invoke is `invoke(Object obj, Object... args)`. `obj` has to be the this-Object. Since your method is static, there is no this object, you may pass null, but you must not omit it, i.e. following works:

```
final Method method = SpHttpClient.class.getDeclaredMethod("fun", HttpClient.class);
method.setAccessible(true);
Object actual = method.invoke(null, mockHttpClient);
```

Comment: By using `spHttpClient.getClass()` can we get method in ENUM type ?

Comment: Use `SPHttpClient.class`. By the way: This problem has nothing to do with reflection. If this was your problem you better had mentioned that a NullPointerException occured.